# I2S Transmitter Verilog Implementation not working

Tags: verilog

I am trying to implement the I2S Transmitter in verilog. The datasheet for it is at: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/I2SBUS.pdf

I wrote the code, but my SD line is delayed 1 clock cycle when i test it.
Can someone check my implementation?

```
module Transmiter(
    input signed [23:0] DLeft, input signed [23:0] DRight, input WS, input CLK,
    output reg SD
    );

  wire PL;
  reg Q1,Q2;
  reg [23:0] shift_reg;
  reg [23:0] Tdata;


   assign PL = Q1^Q2;



   always @(posedge CLK)
    begin
       Q1 <= WS;
       Q2 <= Q1;
    end


    always @( Q1)  begin
       if (Q1)  
         begin
         Tdata <= DRight;
         end
       else
          begin
          Tdata  <= DLeft;
          end
    end



   always @(negedge CLK)
       begin   

           if(PL)
           begin
              shift_reg <= Tdata;
           end
           else begin

           SD <= shift_reg[23];
           shift_reg <= {shift_reg[22:0],1'b0};
           end
       end


endmodule
```

EDIT: here is a image of waveform [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bZjI.jpg)

TEST BENCH CODE:

```
module Transmitter_tb(

    );


    reg CLK, WS;
    reg [23:0] dataL;
    reg [23:0] dataR;

    wire SDout;



    Transmiter UT(dataL, dataR, WS, CLK, SDout);

    initial begin 
    dataL = 24'hF0F0FF; #2;
    dataR = 24'h0000F0; #2;

    end



    always begin
     CLK=0; #20;
     CLK=1; #20;
    end;

        always begin
     WS=0; #1000;
     WS=1; #1000;
    end;





endmodule
```

Comment: Please add more details - your testbench code, your waveform where you see SD delayed, and where exactly is the issue?

Comment: `always@( Q1 )` should be `always@(Q1 or DRight or DLeft)` not sure if that's the issue though.

Comment: @Hida DRight and DLeft are constant values, i am looking for the change in Q1. Based on Q1 either R or L is loaded into Tdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `negedge` block contains an `if-else` construct and will only ever compute one or the other on a single clock edge. `SD` will therefore not change value when `PL` is high.

Furthermore you are using non-blocking assignments(`<=`) in your code. This roughly means that changes won't be evaluated until the end of the always block. So even if `SD <= shift_reg[23]` after `shift_reg <= Tdata` it will not take on the new value in `shift_reg[23]` but use the previous value. If you want `SD` to change immediately when `shift_reg[23]` changes you need to do this combinatorically.

This should work:

```
always @(negedge CLK)
   begin   

       if(PL)
       begin
          shift_reg <= Tdata;
       end
       else
          shift_reg <= {shift_reg[22:0],1'b0};
   end
   assign SD = shift_reg[23];
```

Working example: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4bPv

On a side note I am still not convinced that `DRight` and `DLeft` are in fact constants, I can see that they are in your TB but it doesn't make sense that the data for your I2S is constant. Your current construct will probably generate a latch(instead of a MUX), and we generally don't want those in our design.

Comment: When i say DRight and DLeft are constant, i mean that my if-else statement in the code does not depend on them. Because i am simply copying either one of them to a tempdata location based on the value of Q1. In general, yes, DRight and DLeft will be changing, but i am not copying them to a temp location when they change, only when Q1 changes. Q1 selects either DRight and DLeft. to be shifted out.

Comment: This fix worked, and i understand what you mean now.  I also had to change the WS clock cycle to 960ns. But everything works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should clean up your use of blocking versus non-blocking statements:

Always use non-blocking assigments, meaning "<=", in clocked statements.

Always use blocking assigments, meaning "=", in combinational (non-clocked) statements.

This is a industry-wide recommendation, not a personal opinion. You can find this recommendation many places, see for instance:

http://web.mit.edu/6.111/www/f2007/handouts/L06.pdf

The sensitivtity list being incomplete (as pointed out by @Hida) may also cause issues.

Try to correct these two things, and see if it starts working more as expected.

Also note that you are using Q1 (among other signals) to generate your PL signal. If the WS input is not synchronous to your local clock (as I assume it is not), you need to put one more flop (i.e. two in series) before starting to use the output, to avoid metastability-issues. But you won't see this in an RTL simulation.